# Connect Django with Azure PostgreSQL using managed identity in azure

Tags: django, postgresql, azure, azure-managed-identity

How can I configure Azure PostgreSQL database in Django `settings.py` using Managed Identity in Azure?

Comment: Coudl you explain what you have tried for the moment ? I imagine latest azure python SDK should be able to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

> How to configure Azure PostgreSQL database in Django settings.py using Managed Identity In Azure?

As per the documentation:

**1. Create a PostgreSQL user for Managed Identity:**

```
SET aad_validate_oids_in_tenant = off;
CREATE ROLE myuser WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'CLIENT_ID' IN ROLE azure_ad_user;
```

**2. Settings.py:**

```
DATABASES={
   'default':{
      'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
      'NAME':os.getenv('DATABASE_NAME'),
      'USER':os.getenv('DATABASE_USER'),
      'PASSWORD':os.getenv('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
      'HOST':os.getenv('DATABASE_HOST'),
      'PORT':'5432',
      'OPTIONS': {'sslmode': 'require'}
   }
}
```

**3. requirements.txt:**

```
Django==2.2.17
postgres==3.0.0
psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
psycopg2-pool==1.1
pytz==2020.4
```

You can refer to [Connect with Managed Identity to Azure Database for PostgreSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-connect-with-managed-identity) and [Tutorial: Deploy Django app on AKS with Azure Database for PostgreSQL - Flexible Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/tutorial-django-aks-database)